# jackson jsonsubtypes fields do not bind in case of multilevel hierarchy

Tags: inheritance, jackson

```
    @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type", visible = true)
    @JsonSubTypes({@Type(value = FieldGroupDefault.class, name = "fieldGroupDefault"),
            @Type(value = FieldGroupExtension.class, name = "fieldGroupExtension")})

    public abstract class FieldDTO {

        private String id;
        private String type;
    }

   class FieldDTO have some common attributes.

    public class FieldGroupExtension extends FieldGroup {
      private ViewTypeDefinition viewTypeDefinition;
    }
    class FieldGroupExtension extends the FieldGroup class.


    public abstract class FieldGroup extends FieldDTO {
        private Preview preview;
        private List<FieldDTO> childHierarchy;
    }

   class FieldGroup extends the FieldDTO class.

    public class ViewTypeDefinition {

        private String viewType;
        private List<ColumnDefinition> columnDefinitionList;
    }


        when we send a type as fieldGroupExtension then it call a FieldGroupExtension class based on type but not extends the fieldGroup class.it means not recognize a preview ,childHierarchy variables of class FieldGroup.

           Request Sample : 

        {
                        "type": "fieldGroupExtension",
                        "id": "id_mobile",
                        "label": "+",
                        "preview": {
                            "previewHierarchy": [{
                                "type": "label",
                                "style": "label",
                                "label": "Add another Mobile Number",
                                "hint": "Add another Mobile Number",
                                "id": "id_addAnotherMobile",
                                "visible": true,
                                "isGroup": "false"
                            }]
                        },
                        "childHierarchy": [{
                            "type": "actionInput",
                            "editable": true,
                            "style": "actionInput",
                            "contentDesc": "Add Mobile No ${id_mobile.size()}",
                            "hint": "Add Mobile No ${id_mobile.size()}",
                            "label": "Add Mobile No ${id_mobile.size()}",
                            "id": "id_mobileNo",
                            "actionHint": "Validate",
                            "actions": [{
                                "name": "delete_field"
                            }],
                            "url": "API for validate mobile number",
                            "deepLink": "airtelapp://main",
                            "customStyle": {
                                "iconAlignment": "top",
                                "stickToParent": "bottom"
                            }
                        }],
                        "viewTypeDefinition": {
                            "viewType": "outletList",
                            "columnDefinitionList": [{
                                    "displayValue": "Shop_Address",
                                    "Expression": ""
                                },
                                {
                                    "displayValue": "Role"
                                },
                                {
                                    "displayValue": "View"
                                },
                                {
                                    "displayValue": "Edit"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
```

when we send a request param as described above then we get a request on controller like :

FieldGroupExtension(viewTypeDefinition=ViewTypeDefinition(viewType=outletList, columnDefinitionList=[ColumnDefinition(displayValue=Shop_Address, Expression=null), ColumnDefinition(displayValue=Role, Expression=id_cpRole), ColumnDefinition(displayValue=View, Expression=null), ColumnDefinition(displayValue=Edit, Expression=null)]))

Answer (score 0):

see this: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/374

It is not supported and there are no plans to support it. Do not design your system assuming this will be implemented.

And I have no idea what " tried custom JsonDeserialize but didn't work." means -- custom deserializers can support LITERALLY anything.